# Menu Dropdown do bootstrap não está funcionando

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Meu menu dropdown não funciona.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Menu Dropdowb</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascrip">
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
});
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
});
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
     }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o HTML do drop down?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa. 
O HTML não cabe.
O que eu coloquei foi o do dropdown e a ativação do javascipt.
Obrigado.

Comment: Por favor, crie um snippet de código, reproduzindo o problema, para que fique mais fácil ajudá-lo. Adicione também se puder um print da sua tela, caso o problema seja com a apresentação. Adicione informações sobre qual browser está usando, qual sistema, assim teremos mais contexto para poder dar uma resposta mais assertiva.

Comment: tente utilizar o https://jsfiddle.net/ para ter um exemplo real para que possamos te ajudar rapidamente.

Comment: eu coloquei o css, mas não os scripts javascript do bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Bootstrap possui uma dependência: [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/). Basta incluir o código da biblioteca antes de incluir o arquivo `bootstrap.js` (ou `bootstrap.min.js`).

```html
<!doctype html>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Menu Dropdown</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="caret"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Renan.
Bastou incluir o `<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>`.
Fiz as correções conforme o seu exemplo.

Comment: como faz com o jquery 3 ???

Answer (score 0):

Veja se não está faltando o `<!DOCTYPE html>` no topo do documento HTML.

Se não tiver isso, vai ficar esquisito mesmo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao colocar o `DOCTYPE` corretamente vai ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está com Doctype no inicio.
Estranho que ele esta preto.
Obrigado pela dica.
Mas eu copiei e colei e nada, ainda.

Comment: Você poderia adicionar um print da sua tela na questão, ou então criar um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ou um snippet que reproduza o problema?